# Mozilla Firefox 57 Not Working With Microsoft Outlook Webpage

Tags: kubuntu, firefox

I recently installed Kubuntu 17.10 onto the HDD in my laptop while leaving two partitions and an SSD for dual booting Windows (primarily for my games). I should add that this is my first real, hands-on experience with Linux. I prefer to use Mozilla Firefox and need to use Microsoft Outlook for my school email. I did some tinkering around in Linux, but whenever I attempted to connect to the Outlook website from Mozilla 57 on the school network, it fails to connect. I installed Google Chrome and it connects just fine, but won't with Mozilla 57. I don't want to use Google Chrome, and have been considering backtracking to a previous version of Mozilla to see if it will connect, but I am having trouble with installing the previous version properly because I am so new to all of this, so I haven't tried that yet. I also checked, and I can connect to other websites and other Microsoft Websites, but so far I can't connect to Outlook.

What should I do? If you could include an explanation of your recommendation as well, that'd be great!

Comment: First of all, my FF57 with Outlook works fine. So.... 

[A] what error messages do you get ?
[B] Where in the process does it fail ?
[C] Which add-ons do you have that may be blocking something?
[D] Can you connect when not on the school LAN ?
[E] Do other users have an issue with FF ?

Comment: I have not had the opportunity of trying it on a network outside of the school network. The error I get is "Server Not Found" in the tab title and "We can't connect to the server at `insert school email url`" It fails after briefly attempting to connect. I have read about some other people having this issue, but when I attempted what worked for them, it didn't work for me (maybe because I didn't do it right). I don't believe I have any add-ons, I installed FF from the terminal with `sudo apt-get install firefox`.

Comment: You also mentioned Chrom works ok, so one other thing to check would be the Proxy in Chrome and the Proxy in FF. Make sure they're the same, which should be "default" or similar.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but it started to work. I messed around with some in-browser caches, cookies, and proxy settings, as well as pressing "the reset to default" button for the home page exactly 6 times and suddenly I could connect. But later that day, for some unknown reason, it stopped connecting. I think that this is just an issue that Microsoft has to deal with considering the overhaul changes made to FF57. Regardless, I'm using Chrome to connect to just my email and FF57 for everything else.